# Webstorm Typescript support - Could not find symbol?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

I have code like this in my `.ts` file

`test.control('test-change', TestChange);`

My `test` module is initialized in `lib/test.ts`, and it is properly transpiling to `test.js`.

However, when I write the above code, webstorm throws this error on that line of code:

`error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'test'.`

Is there any solution within Webstorm to avoid this error? The code seems perfectly fine, and it even worked previously. I am also using code that has worked within Visual Studio, so it seems like the code is not the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio implicitly includes all TypeScript files in your project into the global namespace. For compiling with `tsc` manually or using Webstorm / whatever else you need to have explicit references.

```
/// <reference path="../path/to/lib/test.ts"/>
```

You can potentially just use a `reference.ts` https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation although I no longer recommend that

Grunt-ts can take `///ts:ref=test` and generate a reference tag for you.

Comment: Following the above still leaves me with the same errors :/ I tried referencing the file directly as well as using `grunt-ts` to create a `reference.ts` file and referencing that instead. For what it's worth, it does seem that the code is actually building and working now, it just fills my console up with `Could not find symbol` errors.

Comment: +1 nice answer. Could you please elaborate on why you `no longer recommend that`?

Comment: @llya Thanks. From the link https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation `Warning: Using the compiler with --out / reference.ts will slow down a fast compile pipeline. Use external modules with transforms instead.`